# Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack Windows 10 Build 1607

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows

The download site for the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321) states that it is for the following supported operating systems:

Windows 7 Service Pack 1, 
Windows 8.1, 
Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, 
Windows Server 2012, 
Windows Server 2012 R2

Notice that Windows 10 is not listed.  The problem being that Windows 10 does not ship with it.  My only conclusion is that the Microsoft download site is wrong! Because how would you build applications targeting the new framework ?

Has anyone else noticed this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an alternate page which says that the Developer Pack is for Windows 10 Version 1607, Windows 8.1, Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1), Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/3151934

If you click the download link on that page, then you are redirected to the page that you are referring to.

So documentation on the download page appears to be out of date.

Comment: I came across that page also, I installed it on my Win 10 Pro 1607 without any issues, although I don't think it is out of date but an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I installed on Windows 10 and it installed everthing but the main 4.6.2 - however it did install the SDK for 4.6.2 - see the programs and features list after installing - if you look on a Win7 install you will see the main one listed as installed but not in win10 - 4.6.2 is missing on Win10